# How do I parse Python Script(py) file into Java POJOs?

Tags: java, python, unit-testing, parsing, junit

My java code generates Python file from XML input. In order to validate this translation, I would like to go through Python output file and check its content. Right now I am just using String contains method but I think if I could parse Python code into Java POJO, that would make this testing easy. If you think, there is another way to perform this unit testing. Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.jython.org/ might help

Comment: What kind of python code are we talking about, what do you expect this pojo to look like?
You can use jython if you wish to run the python code in your jvm but it doesn't give you tools to inspect the code.

Comment: @Jeppz Input XML has certain states and its transition for example State1>State2>State3 and each state has certain variable declaration and value manipulation. So I want to make sure in Python translation all previous(XML) information present plus order. I don't know how POJO will look like. I feel like string.contains or regex is not smartest way here to test my python output. I thought parsing might be better. Maybe I am wrong. Also I do not wish to execute python code , just inspect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse python code using antlr library. Via antlr you can build AST (Abstract Syntax Trees) and validate it